# How to use Git to restore the changes when certain file exists in a folder?

Tags: git

I am having a folder structure like this in my project folder:

- Folder1

  - Sub folder1
  - Sub folder2
  - Sub sub folder1
  - Sub folder3
- Folder2

  - Sub folder1
  - Sub folder2
    ...

In each folder and its subfolders, there are two .json files called A.json and B.json.

If a folder with only `A.json` modified, do `git checkout <that folder path>`. If a folder with both `A.json` and `B.json` modified, don't do anything.

Example:

- modified:   folder1/subfolder1/A.json
- modified:   folder1/subfolder1/B.json
- modified:   folder2/subfolder1/A.json
- modified:   folder2/subfolder2/A.json

In this case, the "folder2/subfolder1/" and "folder2/subfolder2/" should be restored since they only consist of "A.json". The "folder1/subfolder1/" **should not** be restored since it has both "A.json" and "B.json".

I am not sure if I achieve that by using bash scripts manually to go through each folder.

Comment: CAUTION: this will modify the local filesystem and possibly discard data: `find . -name A.json -exec git checkout {} \;`

Comment: are you looking for `git status -s **/A.json` ?

Comment: @LeGEC Sorry this command filters the modified file with the file name of `A.json`, it does not restore the folders. Please check my updated example for more detail.

Comment: What do you mean by "restore the folders"? `git` knows nothing about directories, and even less about "folders".  Are you saying that if you have a directory in which  A.json is modified and B.json is not modified, you want to restore *all* of the files in that directory?

Comment: @WilliamPursell This command restores the `A.json` when the folder consists of both `A.json` and `B.json`. How do I avoid that? Also, can we improve the efficiency of this command since I have thousands of folders with `A.json` files and the looping through all of them is a bit slow? Please check my updated example for more detail.

Comment: It's still not clear to me if the status of B.json is relevant, or only its existence.  You say that all of the directories have both files, so I suppose you are wanting to check whether or not B.json is modified.  But it's not clear to me what you mean by "it does not restore the folders."

Comment: @WilliamPursell Sorry for the confusion. If a folder with only `A.json` is modified. I want to do `git restore <that folder path>`. If a folder with both `A.json` and `B.json` is modified, I want to skip that folder (do nothing). Hope that clarifies my requirement.

Comment: Note from the documentation for `git-restore`; THIS COMMAND IS EXPERIMENTAL. THE BEHAVIOR MAY CHANGE.  You should probably stick with `git checkout`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: this command has been "experimental" for a while now (it was introduced in git 2.23 in august 2019). The doc still has that sentence but this command is here to stay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

note: this answer works if you don't have `{A,B}.json` files at nested levels.

e.g, you would have an issue with:

```
* Folder1
  * A.json
  * B.json
  * subfolder1
    * A.json
    * B.json
```

because running `git restore ... -- Folder1` would also reset `Folder1/subfolder1`

Please update your question if you have that situation.

---

You can do it with a bit of scripting:

```
# will list the directories with a 'A.json' file modified:
A_modified () {
    git status -s **/A.json | cut -c4- |\
    xargs --no-run-if-empty dirname
}
# explanations:
#  - get short form status of all files named 'A.json' under your repo
#  - strip the leading 3 characters
#  - keep only the 'dirname' part


# will list the directories with a 'B.json' file modified:
B_modified () {
    git status -s **/B.json | cut -c4- |\
    xargs --no-run-if-empty dirname
}

# remove from 'A_modified' the items exactly mentioned in 'B_modified'
A_and_not_B () {
    A_modified | grep -v -f <(B_modified)
}
# explanations:
#  grep -v  : *ignore* lines that match a pattern (I guess you already knew that one ...)
#       -f ... : read patterns from a file rather than from a command line
#       <(cmd) : turn "the stdout of that command" into something that can be
#                passed as a file on the command line
#       (so called "process substitution", this is part of bash, zsh and some other shells)


# feed the output of A_and_not_B as paths to git restore:
A_and_not_B | xargs --no-run-if-empty git restore -SW -s HEAD --
```